# arabic word changed to ???? after inserting into Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, mybatis

when I insert data in this table, my query is 
INSERT INTO urdu_word (word) VALUES ('Abdelali Abou Dher (عبد العالي ابو ذر)') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE word='Abdelali Abou Dher (عبد العالي ابو ذر)' word value replace to like ???

My table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `urdu_word` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `word` (`word`),
  KEY `idx_aml_word_status` (`word`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I also tried to chage table structure to utf8_unicode_ci but same problem facing

```
CREATE TABLE `aml_word` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `word` (`word`),
  KEY `idx_aml_word_status` (`word`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

mysql version 5.6

when insert query run in mysql command line then it inserted well in urdu but when I inserted through code using mybatis ORM then create problem.

Comment: You might consider chaning 'word' to `nvarchar(255)`, and cast it as unicode when inserting... i.e. `UPDATE word=N'Abdelali Abou Dher (عبد العالي ابو ذر)'`

Comment: You should post a base64 or hex encoded example of a string both before inserting and after retrieval. Then we can verify that the input string is encoded properly, and examine what happened to the output.

Answer (score 0):

> The default character set for MySQL at (mt) Media Temple is latin1,
>   with a default collation of latin1_swedish_

So you need to change your callation

Try with this query

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Followed by this tutorial

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403914/default-mysql-character-set-and-collation#gs